# How do I get the value of a clicked button on previous page

Tags: javascript, html

My Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="document.location='target.html'" name="this" type="submit" value="hello" >target</button>
</body>
</html>
```

My Target.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>2nd page</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

I would like to access the have access to the value of the clicked button on index.html so i can use it anywhere on the target.html page

In my head it looks something like this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

var buttonval = value of button click
<html>
<body>

<h1>2nd page</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Ideally I would like to achieve this using only html and java script

Comment: Use localstorage/session storage to store value

Answer (score 2):

You first need to send the value, so based on your code it would go something like this:

```
<button onclick="document.location='target.html?val=hello'" name="this" type="submit" value="hello" >target</button>
```

And then you need to recover that value on the target page:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
var val = url.searchParams.get("val");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET method (value in the Url) or POST method (use <FORM).

Here in Get :

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="document.location='target.html?val=1234'" name="this" type="submit" value="hello" >target</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Target.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   <h1>2nd page</h1>    
   <div id="val"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("?");
    console.log(parameters);
    var vals = parameters[0].split("=");
    console.log(vals);
    document.getElementById("val").innerHTML = "value = "+vals[1];
</script>
</html>
```

See informations in the Console (F12) in your Browser.

Good continuation.
*_Teddy_*

Answer (score 0):

Use Page Including Using PHP

```
example : <?php include("page.php"); ?>
```

perform click direct in visible file.